# Changing Scala sources directory in SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm having quite a few troubles pointing at a custom directory for Scala source-files in SBT.

I would like sbt to compile scala-files from a given directory instead of the regular `src/main/scala` directory.

I have tried both defining a .sbt and .scala project files, setting `baseDirectory`, `scalaSource` (and `scalaSource` **s** in the .scala file). I've also toyed around with everything from system-absolute to relative paths but nothing seems to work. It cannot locate any .scala file under the specified directory.

What are the proper ways to handle this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this in *build.sbt*:

```
scalaSource in Compile <<= (sourceDirectory in Compile)(_ / "foo")
```

This will result in a directory *src/main/foo* for Scala sources. If you want to use some arbitrary directory, go for this:

```
scalaSource in Compile := file("/Users/heiko/tmp")
```

Comment: Great! This is just what I needed. Funny I never ran into this before. Thanks :)

Comment: Just for future reference; After a lot of searching I found that the .scala files wasn't compiled because everything beneath src/ was ignored, except for scala/ and java/. The solution was to add the dir to the compile-directories like so: sourceDirectories in Compile += new File("/dir/to/scala/src")

Comment: Not the best solution! Why do you redefine sourceDirectories? Usually you better redefine scalaSource.

Comment: If you want to just have source in src, not src/main?  (Something like src/com/mystuff/Foo.java)

Comment: What if you want to add multiple source directories

    `??? in Compile <<= Seq(file("src1"), file("src2"))`

Comment: > inspect compile:unmanaged-source-directories

[info] Setting: scala.collection.Seq[java.io.File] = List(/Users/heiko/projects/training-akka/src/main/scala, /Users/heiko/projects/training-akka/src/main/java)
[info] Description:
[info]  Unmanaged source directories, which contain manually created sources.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  {file:/Users/heiko/projects/training-akka/}hakkyhour/compile:unmanaged-source-directories
[info] Dependencies:
[info]  compile:scala-source
[info]  compile:java-source

Answer (score 8):

Update answer for SBT 0.13.13 ->

`sourceDirectory in Compile := (baseDirectory( _ / "foo" )).value`

And to add a source directory (instead of just replacing it) also for SBT 0.13.13 ->

`unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile += (baseDirectory( _ / "foo" )).value`

Comment: This is a bit easier to read: `sourceDirectory in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "foo"` and works just al well.